# Gstreamer sharp start audio playback at offset

Tags: c#, audio, mono, gstreamer

I'm currently investigating gstreamer binding for my application using mono on linux and .net on windows. I was able to get the gstreamer-sharp 0.99.x to run on windows now, so I would like to get the basic binding running.

To the problem:
I generade the playbin with gstreamer sharp the following way:

```
Element music = Parse.Launch("playbin \"uri=file:///c:/tmp/test.wav\"");
```

How can I set the offset of the audio? I tried with

```
music.SeekSimple(Format.Default, SeekFlags.Flush, 7000 * 10 ^ 9);
```

But that only works, if the state is playing. How can I initialise the music element to start at position x?

Thanks in advance
Sven

Comment: You are using the '^' (bitwise XOR) operator, is this intended? I guess you are referring to the millisecond constant which is definded in Gst.Constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeks can only be done when the pipeline is in the playing or paused state. So you probably need to call music.SetState (State.Paused); before calling SeekSimple. Also see http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-eventsseek.html for more information.